# Find $|P|$ if $P= \{(p,q) \in A\times A \mid (p+q) \text{ is prime}\}.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm really confused on where to start with this question. If anyone could give any advice on how to start I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Define $B_k \subseteq A\times A $

by $B_k=\{(p,q) \in A\times A \mid p+q=k\}$

$2\leq k\leq 10$ here

Let

$P= \{(p,q) \in A\times A \mid (p+q) \text{ is prime}\}$

Calculate $|P|$ by finding $|B_k|$ for the appropriate values of $k$ and adding them together.

Comment: Please review my edits to make sure they are accurate. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks Max, I appreciate your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: **find all the options**.

Let  $ P = \bigcup_{p \in Prime}  \{ (a,b) \in A \times A | p=(a+b) \}  $. Now, what is the possiblity of such $ p $-s?